# Font Conversion From TrueType to Postscript Type 1

Tags: unicode, postscript, truetype, fontconfig

I have a TrueType Font and I want to merge it with a Postscript Font File. When I am merging using fontforge I am getting an error:

> TrueType font file is 2 byte Encoded and Postscript is 1 byte

I want to know whether there is any method by which we can merge 2-byte encoded Font files to 1-byte encoded files or is there any way we can convert TrueType fonts (2-byte encoding) to a Postscript File (1-byte encoding)? For example, a Korean font file is 2-byte encoding and I want to merge it with a 1-byte encoded Postscript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using more than 255 glyphs, then you would need to convert the TrueType font into a CIDFont with TrueType outlines, and supply a suitable CMap to map from character codes to CIDs.

Alternatively, or if you only want to use up to 255 glyphs, you can convert the font into a PostScript Type 42 font which is a PostScript method for wrapping a TrueType font so that it can be used. If you want to sue more than 255 glyphs using this method then you need to split the original TrueType font into multiple type 42 fonts and switch font as required to use the glyphs.

But basically you can't combine a TrueType font and a type 1 (or CFF) font succesfully, the technologies are quite different.

Why do you want to do this anyway ?